# Stop automatic change in formulas when inserting a new row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a form that pulls data from a separate tab in the same sheet. Whenever a new row is added on the source tab, the formula on the form updates and does not show the new row.

Is there a way to always have G3 from one sheet show up on another?

This is the formula I'm currently using:
='Sheet 1'!G3

When a new row is added to Sheet 1, the formula updates to
='Sheet 1'!G4

I'm trying to keep the formula on Sheet 2 the same when a row is added to Sheet 1

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=indirect("Sheet 1!G3")
```